# different methods for response Json Array in Laravel 5.1

Tags: json, response, laravel-5.1

what is the difference between return an array as Json Array in these two ways in Laravel 5.1?

```
$a=[1,2,3];
return $a;
// output is [1,2,3]
```

or

```
$a=[1,2,3];
return response()->json($a);
// output is [1,2,3]
```

Answer (score 0):

The seconde way is better.
This synthax add things like http header "application/json" Content-type, etc...
See http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/responses#json-responses,
It's explain

Comment: i have test two way. both of them have application/json header.

Comment: The second way also convert the array to json using the json_encode PHP function